# WebView cutting edge, can't see the web the way it is

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I'm developing an app which has a WebView that opens a website.
I test it on iPod and iPhone for now and it has weird different results.

In iPhone (4S), the edges are cut, while in iPod (Touch 5th gen) it is displayed correctly.

Screenshots:
iPod Touch:

[image: iPod Touch]

iPhone:

[image: iPhone]

Did this happen to anyone before? How can I fix it?

Thank you.

**EDIT**

Some code of the website:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
    <title>P Home</title>       
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="pfmanage.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css">
    <!-- Force latest IE rendering engine or ChromeFrame if installed -->
    <!--[if IE]><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"><![endif]-->
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS fixes for IE6 -->
    <!--[if lt IE 7]><link rel="stylesheet" href="http://blueimp.github.com/cdn/css/bootstrap-ie6.min.css"><![endif]-->
    <!-- Shim to make HTML5 elements usable in older Internet Explorer versions -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script><![endif]-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap_font_awesome/css/font-awesome.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="custom_styles/custom_styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="my_styles/my_styles.css">
    <!-- Bootstrap styles for responsive website layout, supporting different screen sizes -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.css">
</head>
<script>
...
```

My webView Controller function:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

_webView.delegate = self;
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

NSString *PendragonURL= [prefs stringForKey:@"PendragonURL"];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:PendragonURL];
NSURLRequest *requestURL = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[_webView loadRequest:requestURL];
_webView.scalesPageToFit = true;

}
```

**EDIT 2**

Seems like the problem is related with `Constraints`:

If I add/reset missing/suggested constraints in the WebViewController, my iPod works and my iPhone does not.

If I delete all the Constraints none of them work propertly.

Comment: Can you show your code to generate the webview, and possibly some code for the site itself?

Comment: Site head added, but I don't know what are you looking for, the web is huge and has a lot of things and JS.

Comment: About the webView, I use storyboard, so not too much thing codedl just edited the post